# Click in a button overwritten by an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

In my HTML website I have a button, and I try add an transparent image over this button. And I can't click in this button after.
My problem is something like this:

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png" width="200px" ;height="200px" />
  <a href="#">
        Click here
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Bad UX! first impression. why you need it that way? suggestion is to have a lower z-index value than anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this you can set the `z-index` of the image lower than the `a` element (which defaults to `0`)

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png" width="200px" ;height="200px" />
  <a href="#">
    Click here
  </a>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could use the image as a background on the container and avoid the need to position it absolutely, or have to change z-index at all.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a `z-index` to the button and give it position `relative`

```
.button {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

Here is the code you need to use

**html**

```
<div id="container">
<img id="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png" width="200px";height="200px"/>
<a class="button" href="#">
    Click here
</a>
```

**css**

```
#container
{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    position:relative;
}

#image
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.button {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
```

See [js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fv6uqo2a/)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter width and height of image-container as you wish..

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  }
#image-container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png");
  background-position:center;
  background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="image-container">
  <a href="#">
        Click here
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree, using z-index would be better.